# Why is my app telling me my method is undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, debugging

I have this link:

```
<%= link_to_function "remove", "remove_fields(this)"%>
```

which outputs this html:

```
<a href="#" onclick="remove_fields(this); return false;">remove</a>
```

and I have this JQuery function:

```
    function remove_fields(link){
      $(link).prev("input[type=hidden]").val("1");
      $(link).closest(".fields").hide();
    }
```

but when I click on the link, I get this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: remove_fields is not defined
```

Why is this and how do I fix it?

Comment: Where and how is your function defined?

Comment: is it under the jQuery ready statement? try moveing it from there, to a public scope

Comment: it is under the ready statement... how do I move it to a public scope?

Comment: Just move it outside of the `$(document).ready()` function. Also, consider avoiding using `onclick` and register the click event by using JS directly

Comment: i do suggest not mixing jquery with rjs, unless you're using jquery-ujs. rjs usually relies on prototype and there might be some conflicts that might be breaking your code

Comment: @corroded yeah I agree, i'll just go the pure jquery route... thanks

Comment: The accepted answer is the right way to do it. But just FYI: to add it to the global scope:
window.remove_fields = function(link){...};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use the `onclick` attribute, it's a bad practice and something that belongs back in the 90s. Instead you should add a class for your anchors and bind a handler to the click event with jQuery.

**HTML**

```
<a class="remove-fields" href="#">remove</a>
```

**JavaScript**

```
// This is a shorthand for document.ready
$(function(){
    // Bind handler to click event
    $("a.remove-fields").click(function(e){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.prev("input[type=hidden]").val("1");
        $this.closest(".fields").hide();
        // Prevent default behavior
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have your function declaration like this:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    function remove_fields ...
});
```

then it's only in scope inside the `jQuery(function () { })` function and not visible from outside. Two methods of resolving this:

```
var remove_fields;

jQuery(function ($) {
    remove_fields = function () { ... }
});
```

Declares a globally accessible variable and makes it a function as usual.

Better though:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    function remove_fields ...

    $('a.some-class').click(remove_fields);
});
```

Attach the click handler programmatically from within your jQuery scope.

Answer (score 0):

May be obvious, but is the javascript linked in the head in the source of the html?